# I want to make the ethereum wallet using web3.js

Tags: web3js

I synced all ethereum nodes in my localhost and I am connecting my node through this command

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545" \ --rpc --rpccorsdomain "http://127.0.0.1:8545" console
```

and then I am attaching thought this command from node.js cmd

```
geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

then I download web3.js and make one Html page for testing so before I create an account through (geth account new ) from node.js cmd and when and after that I am using some script for checking my create account that is I create thought node.js cmd using (geth account new ) its show perfectly and now i want to create new etherum account using

```
var Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');

// Passing in the eth or web3 package is necessary to allow retrieving chainId, gasPrice and nonce automatically
// for accounts.signTransaction().
var accounts = new Accounts('ws://localhost:8546');
```

so its showing me error that is

> web3-eth-accounts is not found

but you give me the solution for this using this command(`npm install web3-eth-accounts` ) so it successfully install but when i run this (`npm run-script build-all`) so it's not working my node.js cmd and tell me where I had to run this command in the project ?.

and I am also facing this issue

```
npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

audited 118883 packages in 29.686s
found 1766 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1765 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: Based on some discussion in other threads, you mentioned you are trying to create an Ethereum account to be used in Web3.js. Is there a reason you are trying to do this programmatically versus using a wallet like [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/)? This is the standard practice, and makes it really easy to set up a Web3.js front-end. Try looking at this [hello world](https://shawntabrizi.com/crypto/ethereum-web3-js-hello-world-get-eth-balance-ethereum-address/) tutorial.

Comment: getting balance is working fine but when i am trying to create the new account through html page its giving me error

Comment: can we create etherum account using html page like we are using html page for checking balance using some scripts

Comment: You can, but I think that is the wrong practice. You should be letting another service like MetaMask create the accounts for the user. Can you tell me why YOU want to create an account using an HTML page?

Comment: because i want to make web wallet where i can able to send coin ethereum to ethereum

Comment: that user can create account and can send money and can receive money through  my web wallet. i have expertise in laravel and other languages but i am new in etheruem wab wallet etc i just need guide line for this if you help me to solve my problem so it will be very kind thank you

Comment: You want to use something like MetaMask to create and manage your account. Your Web3 website should simply use the MetaMask account to perform actions. Please search for an follow tutorials starting with MetaMask

Comment: i know we can do it from meta mask but i want to create account through my html page using web3 and some scripts can i do?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the installation instructions for `web3-eth-accounts`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-eth-accounts

> ## Installation
>
> ### Node.js
>
> ```
> npm install web3-eth-accounts
> ```
>
> ### In the Browser
>
> Build running the following in the [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) repository:
>
> ```
> npm run-script build-all
> ```
>
> Then include `dist/web3-eth-accounts.js` in your html file. This will
>   expose the `Web3EthAccounts` object on the window object.

Comment: E:\btc1\web3.js-develop>npm run-script build-all
npm ERR! missing script: build-all
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean this?
npm ERR!     build

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are you starting with? Are you using Node.js or are you building a basic HTML/JS page? You can't just paste error messages at us. Update your main post to include more details for better advice.

Comment: npm run-script build-all when i am try to install this i face issue in my web3 project help me

Comment: The error message for the NPM error says `missing script: build-all`. Most probably, there is no `build-all` script defined in the `package.json` file

Comment: @AjoyBhatia could you tell how to add it?

Comment: Why do you want to add a script named `build-all` to the `ethereum/web3.js` module? That code has been written by someone else, who provided the script named `build` to build it. So you just run the command: `npm run-script build`. There is nothing special about the name `build-all`

Answer (score 1):

Installing `web3-eth-accounts` will probably not give a successful build because some other NodeJS module dependency may be missing. So, first execute the following command:

`npm install`

This takes the list of required dependencies from the `package.json` file and installs them all.

Also, I looked at the `package.json` file at https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/package.json and I don't see a script named `build-all` defined in it. Look at the `"scripts"` JSON object in this file. The only scripts you can run (with the command: `npm run-script <script-name>`) are `build`, `watch`, `lint`, `test` and `test-coveralls`. What you want to run is, probably, the following:

`npm run-script build`